# Why is my alert not popping up when it is in if()?

Tags: javascript, forms

The alert is not popping up on the code below, but it works when it is not inside of the if statement. Any help is appreciated.

```
function publish() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var price = document.getElementById("ppd").value;
  var photo = "1";
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

  if ((document.getElementById("name").length = 0)) {
    window.alert("Must enter name");
  }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning the length, not checking it

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign

Comment: In other words, you want to do `document.getElementById("name").length === 0` (or `==` will work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the condition

1. In JavaScript comparison operator is `===` (or `==`). `=` is assignment operator
2. If you're checking input value length, then the code should check `length` of `value` property

```
if (document.getElementById("name").value.length === 0)
```

You can also use the variable `name` directly

```
if (name.length === 0)
```